# Getting the isSelected value of a selected radiobutton in separate class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, visibility, jradiobutton

I realise this is probably the definition of a noob question but I'm pretty stuck and would greatly appreciate any help.

I have an `actionlistener` and `JRadioButton` which is declared in the `ValublesMain` class like this.

```
JRadioButton name = new JRadioButton("Name", true);

name.addActionListener(new NameListener());
```

The `NameListener` is declared further down like this.

```
class NameListener implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            display.setText("");

            for(Valuble item : valubles)    
             if(name.isSelected()){

                 //Bunch of code and stuff

             }

        }

    }
```

The problem I have is that name is not visible and I wonder what I am doing wrong here. I thought that NameListener would be able to see name since it is declared here.

```
name.addActionListener(new NameListener());
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your `actionPerformed` method to get the `JRadioButton` from the `event`

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        display.setText("");

        for(Valuble item : valubles)    
         if(((JRadioButton)event.getSource()).isSelected()){

             //Bunch of code and stuff

         }

    }
```